# Wrong keyboard hide

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have some weird problem with `tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag`.
I lift up my view when `textField` tapped it's ok. Then I want to dismiss my keyboard exactly like in iMessage, but in my case when `keyboardWillHide` notification called `view.frame.origin.y` not equals 0. It's equals 12. Fun fact my code works pretty cool in simulator but this bug only on real iPhone 11. Any ideas what the hell is it?

My code with keyboard notifications

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
            if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
                self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardSize.size.height + (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.bounds.height)!
            }
        }
        
     @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
      }
```

[image]

Comment: You code for responding the keyboard show and hide is probably too simple-minded. Typically, real code would be much more sophisticated about what is happening.

Comment: You are not trying to move the view controller's view are you? That's crazy. You should be moving a subview. Also, what about autolayout? If you are not using autolayout, you should be. But if you do, then you cannot set the frame of a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Troubles was because keyboardWillShow called multiple times.
Code to handle it.

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        var _kbSize:CGSize!
        
        if let info = notification.userInfo {
            
            let frameEndUserInfoKey = UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey
            
            //  Getting UIKeyboardSize.
            if let kbFrame = info[frameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
                
                let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
                
                let intersectRect = kbFrame.intersection(screenSize)
                
                if intersectRect.isNull {
                    _kbSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.size.width, height: 0)
                } else {
                    _kbSize = intersectRect.size
                }
                
                if _kbSize.height != 0 {
                    self.view.frame.origin.y = -_kbSize.height + (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.bounds.height)!
                } else {
                    self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Correct. Note, however, that you are not saying anything new. This very same matter has been explained in exactly that kind of way on Stack Overflow before.